# ui:define with rendered="false" attribute still rendering

Tags: jsf, facelets

```
<ui:define name="description" rendered="false">
    <meta name="description" content="do not render" />
</ui:define>
```

i'm using this code in my xhtml page, when i run the app, meta description is still rendering.  i want to use meta description tag depending on some conditions. master layout:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="description" />
    </h:head>
    ...........
</html>
```

web page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                    
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/templates/masterLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="description" rendered="false">
        <meta name="description" content="do not render" />
    </ui:define>
...........
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`<ui:define>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) is a taghandler which runs during view build time, not an `UIComponent` which runs during view render time. It does therefore [not](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/define.html) support the `rendered` attribute. Any unsupported attribute is just plain ignored.

Use [`<ui:fragment>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html) instead.

```
<ui:define name="description">
    <ui:fragment rendered="false">
        <meta name="description" content="do not render" />
    </ui:fragment>
</ui:define>
```